# How can I obtain minutes and seconds from iphone compass?

Tags: iphone, compass-geolocation

I have an app that uses de iPhone's compass.
I use the CLLocationDirection magneticHeading value. 
It is given only in degrees like 234.543, and when I turn the iPhone, for example, it changes to **235**.543 **236**.543 **237**.543 **238**.543 and so on.
The point value (**.543**) doesn't change. I would like obtain more accuracy than degrees, I mean, I want the point value (**.543**) changes too when I turn the iPhone, or obtain the minutes/seconds value.
Anyone knows how can I have more precision in this value?
Thanks!

Comment: methinks you are being too demanding if you want arc-seconds (or even arc-minutes) precision from an iphone compass

Comment: and why does it give me a floating value that doesn't change in a same lecture?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the iPhone API, but I am familiar with sensors for embedded systems. If it's a magnetic compass sensor, you're probably getting orientation from the sensor with 1 degree resolution. (which is amazing that it can be that accurate, given the relatively small magnetic fields from the Earth)

Try looking at both the magneticHeading and the trueHeading ([per the API docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLHeading_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). I'll bet the magnetic deviation is calculated more precisely than in 1 degree increments, and that's why you're seeing the .543; you might see a different number if you travel 100km east or west.

Comment: yes, it is a magnetic compass sensor, it gives 1 degree resolution. I think you are right and the magnetic desviation is clacluated more precisely, but I have looking for it in the API but I don't find anything that says something more than the degrees value. I have been searching in google but I haven't find anything